# Android view to display true/false value

Tags: android

I was wondering of a View to use to display a true/false value graphically (which means no `TextView` with text "true" or "false"). Obviously the first thought in my mind was to use either `CheckBox` or `Switch` but the issue is they don't seem to have any property that makes them "read only". I'm placing them in a details screen so I don't want the user changing it (unless in an edit screen which needs password but that's out of the topic).

Is there any view to represent true/false value or is there any way to make these views unchangeable by touching?

PS: something like the `ratingBarStyleIndicator` but for true/false

Comment: My first suggestion would be assigning an `ImageView` to one of two possible images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a `CheckBox`, `ToogleButton` or `RadioButton`. If you want to disallow the user from changing the value just set `clickable=false` in the `View`'s xml.

Comment: I wouldn't. Users will expect these to be clickable and will be irritated when they do not appear to work.

Comment: "Is there any view to represent true/false value or is there any way to make these views unchangeable by touching?" I thought that is what he wanted to do? But you are right, not the best UX in my opinion either.

Comment: Oh, your answer is technically fine and definitely answers that part of the question. I'm just commenting on the UX. My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: well yeah, this is the answer I was looking for, but now that you mention it, the user will expect it to be clickable...